# Can't write to /dev/sdc, because it is opened read-only

Tags: filesystem, usb-drive

I have a flash memory that I can delete or write anything to it 
when I try to delete the partition or format it , I got this message

```
Can't write to /dev/sdc, because it is opened read-only.
```

How can format it or be able to write and delete files from it?

```
$ mount | grep /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc1 on /media/karim/3060-070E type vfat (ro,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)

$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0  58.6G  0 part 
├─sda2    8:2    0   100G  0 part 
├─sda3    8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda4    8:4    0   1.1G  0 part 
├─sda5    8:5    0   100G  0 part /media/karim/MP3
├─sda6    8:6    0   100G  0 part 
├─sda7    8:7    0  19.9G  0 part 
├─sda8    8:8    0    58G  0 part /home
├─sda9    8:9    0   1.9G  0 part /opt
├─sda10   8:10   0  18.8G  0 part /
└─sda11   8:11   0   7.5G  0 part [SWAP]
sdc       8:32   0  14.9G  1 disk 
└─sdc1    8:33   0  14.9G  1 part /media/karim/3060-070E
sr0      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Ah, just saw the `usb-storage` tag. Make sure it doesn't have an hardware switch; if it doesn't please add the output of `mount` to the question

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the outputs of `mount | grep /dev/sdc` and `lsblk`.

Comment: Make sure the switch on the card is not flipped to read only mode.

Comment: no it sandisk cruzer 16GB and it doesn't have any hardware switch

Comment: Have you changed `udev` rules?

Comment: Start the following commands and add the output into your question: `sudo umount /dev/sdc1; sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt; mount | grep /dev/sdc; sudo umount /dev/sdc1`

Comment: @A.B. I tried your command and the result is

   mount: block device /dev/sdc1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
/dev/sdc1 on /mnt type vfat (ro)

Comment: @KarimSamir your memory card has a hardware block preventing writing. Most likely a tab or a switch or something.

Comment: When did you buy that thing?

Comment: Are important data contained on the stick?

Comment: no, there is no important data,

Comment: If there is no hardware switch to write protect the drive, unmount if via `sudo umount /dev/sdc1` and delete the whole drive with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M`. After that create a new partition and a new filesystem.

Comment: And no panic, `dd` needs some time... :)

Comment: @A.B. dd returns  dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdc’: Read-only file system

Comment: I tried with  and without sudo

Comment: It's a hardware problem. How old is the stick?

Comment: about a 13 months , here is its url https://www.sandisk.com/home/usb-flash/cruzer-edge, thank you @A.B. for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a `dd` does not work

```
dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdc’: Read-only file system
```

and you, as you say, also have no hardware write protection, I suspect a hardware defect. You can try to change the stick, if you have warranty.

Comment: probably you are right , I have got tired trying to fix it, I will get a new one soon, Thank you